# The repository 'http://http.us.debian.org/debian xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: updates, apt

When I try update my elementary OS I get these error messages:

```
W: The repository 'http://http.us.debian.org/debian xenial Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could you help me to fix this problem?